# Foreign Key referencing inherited table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE mail (
    id serial,
    parent_mail_id integer,
    ...

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_mail_id) REFERENCES mail(id),
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE incoming (
    from_contact_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES contact(id),
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    ---> FOREIGN KEY (parent_mail_id) REFERENCES mail(id), <---
    ...
) INHERITS(mail);

CREATE TABLE outgoing (
    from_user_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "user"(id),
    ...  
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    --> FOREIGN KEY (parent_mail_id) REFERENCES mail(id), <--
    ...
) INHERITS(mail);
```

`incoming` and `outgoing` inherit from `mail` and define their foreign keys (and primary keys) again, as they are not automatically inherited.

The problem is:

If I'd insert an `incoming` mail, it is not possible to reference it from the `outgoing` table as the foreign key only works with the super table (`mails`).

**Is there a workaround for that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PostgreSQL 9.3 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-inherit.html):

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes
>   (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply
>   to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on
>   both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint.
>   Thus, in the terms of the above example:
>
> If we declared cities.name to be UNIQUE or a PRIMARY KEY, this would not stop the capitals table from having rows with names
>   duplicating rows in cities. And those duplicate rows would by default
>   show up in queries from cities. In fact, by default capitals would
>   have no unique constraint at all, and so could contain multiple rows
>   with the same name. You could add a unique constraint to capitals, but
>   this would not prevent duplication compared to cities.
>
> Similarly, if we were to specify that cities.name REFERENCES some other table, this constraint would not automatically propagate to
>   capitals. In this case you could work around it by manually adding the
>   same REFERENCES constraint to capitals.
>
> Specifying that another table's column REFERENCES cities(name) would allow the other table to contain city names, but not capital
>   names. There is no good workaround for this case.
>
> These deficiencies will probably be fixed in some future release, but
>   **in the meantime considerable care is needed in deciding whether
>   inheritance is useful for your application.**

And not really a workaround, so maybe make mails a non-inherited table, and then separate incoming_columns and outgoing_columns for their respective extra columns, with the mail id as both their primary and foreign key. You can then create a view outgoing as mail INNER JOIN outgoing_columns, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a constraint trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mail_ref_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM mail WHERE id = NEW.parent_mail_id
        ) THEN
        RAISE foreign_key_violation USING MESSAGE = FORMAT('Referenced mail id not found, mail_id:%s', NEW.parent_mail_id);
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER mail_fkey_trigger
    AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON incoming
    DEFERRABLE
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE mail_ref_trigger();
```